# How can I update my project from System.runtime 4.0.10.0 to 4.0.20.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-core

I get this error when I build my project:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line Error  CS1705  Assembly
>   'EntityFramework.Core' with identity 'EntityFramework.Core,
>   Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' which has a higher version than
>   referenced assembly 'System.Runtime' with identity 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'  TaaS.DataAccess..NET
>   Platform  C:_REPOSITORIES\taas-application\TaaS-WebApplication\TaaS.DataAccess\TaaSContext.cs    8

How can I update from System.runtime 4.0.10.0 to 4.0.20.0 ?

That is my project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "TaaS.DataAccess Class Library",
  "authors": [ "LisaTatum" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "System.Collections": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "System.Threading": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.10-beta-23019",
    "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.Relational": "7.0.0-beta5"


  },


  "frameworks": {
    "dotnet": { }
  }
}
```

I went to the nuget package manager and searched for updateable packages and there was System.Runtime 4.0.20.0. I updated it and from now on everything is broken thanks to Microsoft. I know its beta but that should not happen:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Warning     Dependency specified was System.Runtime >= 4.0.20 but ended up with System.Runtime 4.0.10-beta-23019.   TaaS.DataAccess C:\_REPOSITORIES\taas-application\TaaS-WebApplication\TaaS.DataAccess\project.json  13
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you update your project.json as follows it will solve the error:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "TaaS.DataAccess Class Library",
  "authors": [ "LisaTatum" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",

  "dependencies": {

    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta7",
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta7"

    }

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50" : {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23225",
        "System.Data.Common": "4.0.1-beta-23225",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23225",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23225",
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23225"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

note that in early beta versions of tooling class library projects were created with the target "dotnet" as you had it but if you create a class library project with the latest beta7 tooling it uses dnx451 and dnxcore50 so that dependencies can be set independently for each framework. The ones labelled beta7 go in the main dependencies because they are needed by both dnx451 and dnxcore50.

Those dependencies which are not labelled as beta7 are only needed for dnxcore50 so I moved them into the dnxcore50 dependencies and also corrected the versions to correspond to beta7 (there is a correspondence even though they are not named beta7). I also removed a couple of references that I think are not needed and perhaps no longer exist as packages for beta7

Comment: copy and paste your json file and rebuild I get 80 errors and my DbContext hovering suggests - via show potential fixes - to install 7.0.0-beta5 of ef... so it does not work here.

Comment: have you updated to the latest beta7 tooling for VS 2015? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738

Comment: are there other projects in your solution that also need the project.json updated?

Comment: Just downloading the big 200 mb msi installer. Did not know there is such a tool :-) Yes my web project will later also depend on the TaaS.DataAccess assembly.

Comment: if you still have errors after updating the tooling then update your question to show also the project.json of your web project

Comment: The web project is just unloaded by I will post it later yes if I run into problems.

Comment: OK. for both projects the entity framework problems are solved. I must say the ef team is really changing a lot from every beta... You know where the ColumnTye("char) method is gone?

Comment: I suggest look through the breaking changes in the announcements repo or post a new question if you don't find what you need. https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues Don't forget to mark this as the answer if it solved your errors

Comment: Did it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655634/entity-framework-7-beta7-has-no-columntype-anymore. THANKS again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to roll the upgrade back, you can do so by typing the following into the Package Manager Console.

```
Uninstall-Package System.Runtime -Force
```

and then

```
Install-Package System.Runtime -Version 4.0.10-beta-23019
```