# Entity Framework 7 Beta7 has no ColumnType anymore

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This code does not compile as the **ColumnType** method is unknown in **EF7 Beta7**.

What is the new method to determine a special column type?

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
                .Property(a => a.ISO639_ISO3166)
                .ColumnType("char")
                .MaxLength(5)
                .Required();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the column type you need to use the [HasColumnType](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/configuring.html#relational-data-type) method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
            .Property(a => a.ISO639_ISO3166)
            .HasColumnType("char")
            .MaxLength(5)
            .Required();
```

And if you are targeting more than one relational provider with the same model then you probably want to specify a data type for each provider rather than a global one to be used for all relational providers:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
            .Property(a => a.ISO639_ISO3166)
            .HasSqlServerColumnType("char")
            .MaxLength(5)
            .Required();
```

Comment: and I thought the .HasColumnType is a boolean expression to check the column type like checking metadata :P